# Please vet - special cases based on proof of $\gcd$ is smallest linear combination

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have worked out two cases based on negative values, for checking my understanding of the subject. 
 The theorem is stated to have the variables used being clear. Although, the derivation of gcd or that part is not shown.

 Statement : Suppose $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$, s.t. both $a,b \ne 0$ (i.e. at 
least one of them is non-zero), then there exists a unique integer $c$ that 
satisfies the condition $c \gt 0, c \mid a, c \mid b$, & $\exists x,y \in 
\mathbb{Z}, c  = ax + by$ is the smallest positive linear combination.
 
Special cases based on the above :
As $a,b$ can be positive, negative, or (but not both) zero. So, to have $c$ as a 
positive smallest integer for negative $a$,or $b$; entails having at least one of $x,y$ being negative, as shown by examples below.

(The reason why these cases are considered is that for the purpose of finding the smallest positive linear combination, finding the $\gcd$ (by Euclidean algorithm) is the shortest route, and later need to consider sign for the coefficients ($x,y$).)

(i) $a=-3, b= -5, \implies$ finding $c = \gcd(3,5) = 1$, with Bezout's 
coefficients given by : $x'=2, y' = 1$. For finding $c$ (as linear combination), with signs considered of $a,b$; the coefficients are : $x=-2, y=1$    
(ii) $a = -3, b = 5, 
\implies$ finding $c =\gcd(3,5) = 1$, with Bezout's coefficients given by : $x'=2, y' = 1$. For finding $c$ (as linear combination), with signs considered of $a,b$; the coefficients are : $x=-2, y=-1$

Comment: @Morgan Rodgers I just want that my details in part (i), (ii) (including everything) is perfectly okay.

Comment: c is just the GCD of (a,b)

Comment: @btcgrl  Yes, it is.

Comment: what I mean is, you dont need any special cases, you can just prove that $(a,b)$ is the smallest linear combination of $a$ and $b$. Unless im missing something

Comment: @MorganRodgers Yes, I wanted that only. The doubts arose due to the fact that for computing $\gcd$ the positive signs are considered. While for computing the $\gcd$'s linear combination coefficients ($x,y$), need have actual signs of $a,b$. Just wanted a case to confirm that.

Comment: @btcgrl Might be your are correct, but I felt doubtful. I feel that you are talking in general sense, but to consider the actual cases gets confusing. Hence, wanted to have a special case.

Comment: What is the good reason for down-voting?

Comment: Please somebody upvote me; else the question is going to be closed automatically. There is nothing to improve upon in the too small question. Also, nothing is pointed for improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a positive linear combination of $a$ and $b$; for instance, using $x=a$ and $y=b$ we have
$$
xa+yb=a^2+b^2>0
$$
By the properties of the natural numbers, there is the minimum positive linear combination, call it $c$. In particular $c=xa+yb$ for some $x$ and $y$.

Now write $a=cq+r$, with $0\le r<c$. Then
$$
r=a-cq=(1-xq)a+(-yq)b
$$
Since $r$ is a linear combination of $a$ and $b$ and is less than $c$, it cannot be positive, by minimality of $c$. Therefore $r=0$ and $c\mid a$.

Similarly, $c\mid b$.

---

Clearly, when $a$ and $b$ are both positive, one among $x$ and $y$, where $c=xa+yb$, must be negative. For instance $a=2$ and $b=3$, we can take $x=-1$ and $y=1$.

However, for $a=-2$ and $b=3$, we can take $x=1$ and $y=1$, but, as well, $x=-2$ and $y=-1$.

Comment: Your second case for negative $a$ or $b$ can be summarized for actual computation of $x,y$ as: If at least one value is negative, then need to find (as usual) the Bezout's coefficients first, and then consider finding the actual signs of $x,y$ for the purpose of getting the $c = \gcd$ as a linear combination. -- I am stating this, as for need find by a short way the value of $c$ first. The shortest path is euclidean algorithm, and the fact that $c = \gcd$.

Comment: Please vet my earlier comment, as this is something practically oriented, as also stated in my edited OP.